# How to combine group of routes in gin?

Tags: go, go-gin

I have created two different Groups for `gin` routing specifically `/user` and `/todo` in two different packages and I want to merge them into one file . Here is my `userroutes.go` file.

```
package userrouter

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

//UserRoutes for user
func UserRoutes() *gin.RouterGroup {

    r := gin.Default()

    v1 := r.Group("/user")
    {

        v1.GET("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        })

    }
    return v1

}
```

and `todoroutes.go` as

```
package todorouter

import (
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

//TodoRoutes for creating Todo
func TodoRoutes() *gin.RouterGroup {

    r := gin.Default()

    v2 := r.Group("/todo")
    {

        v2.GET("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        })

    }
    return v2

}
```

and then want to merge them in `routes.go`.

```
package router

import (
    todo "TODO/api/Routes/Todo/TodoRoutes"
    user "TODO/api/Routes/User/UserRoutes"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)


//Router for all routes
func Router() {
    // r := gin.Default()
    userRoutes := user.UserRoutes()
    todoRoutes := todo.TodoRoutes()

}
```

How can I merge them into one file so that they could be fetched with some prefix `/api` like `localhost:8081/api/user/create` or `localhost:8081/api/todo/create`. Additionaly do I need to create `r := gin.Default()` in every route I've been creating or it can be accomplished using once? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just create a super-group and then create your groups under it. Code example to show what I mean:

```
    router := gin.New()
    
    superGroup := router.Group("/api")
    {
        userGroup := superGroup.Group("/user")
        {
            // user group handlers
        }
    
        todoGroup := superGroup.Group("/todo")
        {
            // todo group handlers
        }
    }
```

With this code you can't create your groups as you are doing now, because both your functions `todorouter.TodoRoutes` and `userrouter.UserRoutes` instantiate their own `gin.Engine`. So you have to move the top-level engine and `/api` group to a common place.

If you want, you can then pass the api group object as a function argument. Example:

```
//TodoRoutes for creating Todo
func TodoRoutes(apiGroup *gin.RouterGroup) {

    v2 := apiGroup.Group("/todo")
    {

        v2.GET("/hello", func(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
        })

    }
}
```

However my recommendation to keep your code well organized is to instantiate all routers in the same place, and then place the handlers in separate packages.

```
// package todoroutes
func HandleHello(c *gin.Context) {
            c.JSON(200, gin.H{
                "message": "pong",
            })
}

// package router
    router := gin.New()
    
    superGroup := router.Group("/api")
    {
        userGroup := superGroup.Group("/user")
        {
             userGroup.GET("/hello", todoroutes.HandleHello)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Though I've one doubt regarding last recommendation. Won't it become a little messy if I keep adding Routes in either userGroup or say todoGroup? Just a thought

Comment: I think the key point that means you can structure the endpoints as you prefer was this part of the answer: "pass the api group object as a function argument".

Answer (score 9):

This answer is based on [blackgreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608429/how-to-combine-group-of-routes-in-gin). This is my solution to a similar problem. I created a supergroup ("/api/v1") then add the child groupes ("users", "books") under it. I was able to place the child groupes into different files and send them a single instance of `gin.RouterGroup()`. As the result I have this nice and clean folder structure:

```
controllers/
  user_controllers
  book_controllers
routes/
  user_routes
  book_routes
  index
middlewares/
  all
main.go
```

main.go

```
func startServer() {
    app := gin.New()

    router := app.Group("/api/v1")
    routes.AddRoutes(router)

    utils.ConnectDatabase()

    app.Run(":5500")
}
```

routes/book_routes.go

```
package routes

func bookRoutes(superRoute *gin.RouterGroup) {
    booksRouter := superRoute.Group("/books")
    {
        booksRouter.GET("/", controllers.BookControllers.GetBooks)

        booksRouter.POST("/", controllers.BookControllers.CreateBook)
    }
}
```

routes/user_routes.go

```
package routes

func userRoutes(superRoute *gin.RouterGroup) {
    userRouter := superRoute.Group("/users")
    {
        userRouter.GET("/", controllers.UserControllers.GetUsers)

        userRouter.POST("/", controllers.UserControllers.CreateUser)
    }
}
```

routes/index.go

```
func AddRoutes(superRoute *gin.RouterGroup) {
    bookRoutes(superRoute)
    userRoutes(superRoute)
}
```

Thanks stackoverflow community