# Suggest a better way to implement the routes in golang rest api app

Tags: go, routes, go-gin

Might you be able to steer me in the right direction to enhance the efficiency of implementing routes.

I'm currently using the below code snippet to implement the routes.

```
func NewRouter() *gin.Engine {
router := gin.New()
router.Use(gin.Logger())
router.Use(gin.Recovery())

health := new(controllers.HealthController)

router.GET("/health", health.Status)
router.Use(middlewares.AuthMiddleware())

v1 := router.Group("v1")
{
    userGroup := v1.Group("user")
    {
        user := new(controllers.UserController)
        userGroup.GET("/:id", user.Retrieve)
    }
}
return route
}
```

Comment: Do you see a problem in the way you implement it? This part of the code runs once in the lifetime of an application. Very little can be gained by making it more efficient.

Comment: I have 100+ routes in a single file. How can I efficiently separate the route in a respective module?

Comment: have a look at this answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62608429/how-to-combine-group-of-routes-in-gin/71804392#71804392]